# Why can't python sockets resolve url's with http in it

Tags: python, linux, sockets, http, python-3.x

My Script basically looks like this

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('http://goal.com', 80))
```

i am getting an error, like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danidee/PycharmProjects/b&h/dang.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.connect(('http://goal.com', 80))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

This means that python can't resolve that particular host,

if i remove the `http://` and leave it as `goal.com` or make that request through my browser, it's just fine and the script and the browser don't throw any errors, one of the answers on stackoverflow suggested removing proxies which I've done but the error doesn't go away, from the terminal I've tried

```
host http://goal.com
```

but it does not resolve also, I'm guessing this is something from my system configuration but i can't figure it out I've looked into `/etc/hosts`, but i did not see anything weird there.

i know i could just do without the `http://` but i would like to know why it doesn't work that way, and also what if i want to specify another protocol like `https` or `ftp`

for ftp i've seen codes that do `ftp.goal.com` for example and it seems to work fine for them but i tried that with `http` and it still failed.

Comment: i hope `goal.com` is not going to be angry, i've tried this with several sites and it's the same behaviour

Comment: In the future consider using `example.com` for examples. They wont mind.

Comment: If you just want to perform an HTTP request, consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: All the answers are good I wish I could mark all of them but I can't :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this to be answered, you need to understand how the [TCP/IP stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) works. BTW, I'll just ignore the OSI model because it is mostly useless in most real-world situations.

At the bottom of all, we have the protocols used to transfer bits and bytes between physical/wireless links. This includes things such as [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet), [802.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11), [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_access_control) stuff, etc... It's a direct comunication from one machine directly connected to another machine. Period.

Then, over that, we have one of the gems of protocol design, the [Internet Protocol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol). Unlike what you may think, it's a (relatively) very simple protocol. It's purpose is to define the concepts of hosts, addresses, routing, quality of service, and a few other things. It's very minimalistic in perspective. Thanks to the IP, one machine can *indirectly* connect to another through a whole arrangement of networks and gateways (that usually means routers).

The IP by itself, however, has certain pitfalls. Namely...

- There's no concept of ports.
- Everything must be represented by internet addresses, that is, there are no `thingslikethis.com`, also known as domains.
- The IP is *unreliable*, meaning that packets can get lost (with no notification whatsoever), duplicated, corrupted, etc... This *does* happen in *modern* networks. There's no concept of "connection" whatsoever. Just packets, period.

So, to solve (most) of these problems, comes a not-so-bright gem in protocol design, the [Transmission Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). Note: Ignored UDP for straightforwardness' sake. The TCP's purpose is to allow a *reliable* and *stateful* connection to be established over an unreliable routing protocol, usually the IP. To do so, it adds a considerable overhead to the packets, which is sometimes undesirable. It also has some nice extra features, such as ports. The idea is that a port represents a "service" or "application" that runs inside a host, along with other applications. This is a primordial concept of [multitasking systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking). A pair made up of a host's address and a port is referred to as a "socket". A pair of sockets, one in host A pointing to host B, and another in host B pointing to host A, upon [three-way handshaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking#TCP_three-way_handshake), is called a connection. Thanks to the TCP, we can now say things such as `192.168.1.123:8080`, send data there, and be confident that the data either never reaches the destination, or reaches it successfully and correctly. However, still no domains!

Enters the [Domain Name System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). It defines a hierarchical structure of "domains", symbolical names representing either a host or another hierarchical structure of the same kind. For instance, we have the top-level domain `com`, and its subdomain `google`, which happens to refer to `201.191.202.174`. We refer to domains in reverse-order notation, separated by dots, in the style of `google.com`. With the IP plus the TCP plus the DNS, we can know say things such as `google.com:21`, and get a reliable connection to it. Hurray!

It's now worth noting that when Python talks about "sockets", like most libraries/languages/operating systems, it's talking about sockets in the sense of the TCP. And, as we already know, TCP can only handle things of the style `192.168.1.123:8080`. However, Python's `socket.socket.connect`, though mostly a wrapper around it, gives you a little abstraction over C/POSIX's [`connect(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/connect), and it is that it performs that appropriate dances with the DNS if a hostname is provided instead of an actual address. Nonetheless, the abstraction ends there.

However, what about funky things such as `https://qwe.rty.uio/asd/fgh.html`? To solve this, enters one of the most complex parts of the equation. Understood by none but glorified by all, the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). HTTP is somewhat of a vagely multipurpose protocol. On its basis, it defines [Uniform Resource Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier), which are most of the time [Uniform Resource Locators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). This allows you to use the slash (`/`) after a domain in order to address a "resource" inside it, such as an image or webpage. URIs also define the way the resource is accessed (`http://` means "through the HTTP", `https://` means "through the [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)", `ftp://` means "through the [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)", etc...). HTTP adds a uncountable amount of extra funky things that are necessary for the [World Wide Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web) (often incorrectly called "the Internet") to work the way it does, such as sessions, authentication, encryption, status codes, caching, proxies, file downloads, etc...

**tl;dr**: Python's `socket` library is a thin wrapper around C's that happens to add a DNS resolution vanguard mechanism. Excluding this, it works with vanilla TCP concepts.

Comment: Thank you for going out of your way to explain the TCP/IP model and relating to my question

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to connect a socket using a URL. URL is a uniform resource locator, which has information on **where** to find the resource and **how** to retrieve it. The "where" part is the hostname, port and path, the how is the protocol (`http://`). When you type just the hostname in your browser, it will assume http as protocol.

In your example you create the socket with the `socket.AF_INET` argument, which means that it'll handle addresses of the IPv4 family. Python sockets understand [many address families](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f5ee8e44e1b9567f1ca2eaeae25624cecdf6ddd1/Modules/socketmodule.c#L1453) and (as pointed out by an other answer) add magic DNS resolving to the mix. In this case it is trying to connect to a host named "http://goal.com", which obviously is not what you want.

The socket itself does not understand protocols. It is your responsibility to speak the right protocol through the socket.

The reason you might be able to connect to `ftp.goal.com` is that there exists a subdomain *`ftp`* at `goal.com`.

Since it seems you are trying to speak the HTTP protocol using a URL, I'd recommend you take a look at the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. It is made for just that.

Answer (score 3):

Sockets connect to hosts, not urls.  Socket processing is low-level and has no concept of urls - it deals with machines and ports.